# Expand a div fullscreen from inside a div with scroll

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-transitions

I am trying to create a "complex" animation where a div in a carousel (a simple parent with scroll on the X axis) expands to fullscreen when clicked.

I am trying different options but can't obtain the result.

[Here the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsck95bf/)

Actually I am trying to hide the others and remove the overflow, but can't expand the node in fullscreen. I should use absolute positioning but in that way I cannot position the divs in the horizontal scroller.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".project").forEach(function(n) {
n.onclick = e => {
console.log("deee", e.clientY, e.clientX);

document.querySelector(".carousel").style.overflowX = "visible";

e.currentTarget.classList.add("opened");
document.querySelectorAll(".project:not(.opened)").forEach(n => {
  n.style.display = "none";
});
return;
```

};
});

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How do you exit that "fullscreen"? BTW the best way I can think of is to: 1. clone the selected element. 2. Calculate the position inside the scrollable parent - convert the position into viewport position. 3. append the clone to body at that coordinates. 4. Scale to fullscreen. 5. on *exit* - scale (resize) down the clone to the original element coordinates with fadeout and destroy on animationend.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the codes in your CSS with the selector of .project.opened with this

```
.project.opened {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```